# My array of objects updates the last element with the new object added

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, pinia

I created a web application that has chat feature, using Laravel + Vue. whenever i send a message i added the message to an array using unshift() method to display it like that of messenger app. However, it updates the last element in my array of object. I also use pinia store. To better understand the problem a code is shown below.

In my storeChats.js (this is my Pinia store file for chats)

```
import axios from "axios";
import { ref } from "vue";
import { defineStore } from "pinia"

export const useChatStore = defineStore('Chat', () => {
const conversation = ref(new Array())

return {conversation}
})
```

then in my chat component i have this code

```
//some code for template

//some code for imports

import { useChatStore } from '../../Store/storeChatNotif'

const storeChat = useChatStore();

const message = mess => {
if(mess == '' || !mess) ''
else
    if(mess.trim() != ''){
        
        axios.post('/chat/send', {
            user: storeChat.selectedUserChat.id,
            message: mess
        }).then(res => {
            let data = res.data
            
            if(storeChat.conversation.length == 0)
                storeChat.conversation.push(res.data)
            else{
                
                storeChat.conversation.unshift({...res.data})
            }
      
        }).catch(e => {
            //some code here for error
        })
    }
```

}

my `message()` is the method that sends the message.

each time the use clicks enter or send button the `message()` is triggered

now after the message is send to the server and store it to my database, it responds with the the created message, it returns like this:

```
{
    avatar: null,
    convoId: 53, //their conversation id
    created_at: "2023-03-07T13:11:16.000000Z",
    id: 3,
    message: "hi",
    name: "Anna Doe",
    receiver: 3, // id of the user who will receive the message
    seen: null,
    sender: 1, //id of the user who sends the message
    updated_at:"2023-03-07T13:11:16.000000Z"
}
```

now this object is then added to storeChat.conversation as you can see from the code above in my chat component.

the problem is this, whenever is send a new message it updates the last element in my array of objects which is the storeChat.conversation. So instead of getting a result like this:

```
[
  {
    avatar: null,
    convoId: 53, //their conversation id
    created_at: "2023-03-07T13:15:50.000000Z",
    id: 3,
    message:"hello",
    name: "Anna Doe",
    receiver: 1, // id of the user who will receive the message
    seen: null,
    sender: 3, //id of the user who sends the message
    updated_at: "2023-03-07T13:15:50.000000Z"
  },
  {
    avatar: null,
    convoId: 53, //their conversation id
    created_at: "2023-03-07T13:11:16.000000Z",
    id: 3,
    message: "hi",
    name: "Anna Doe",
    receiver: 3, // id of the user who will receive the message
    seen: null,
    sender: 1, //id of the user who sends the message
    updated_at:"2023-03-07T13:11:16.000000Z"
  }
]
```

i get this:

```
[
  {
    avatar: null,
    convoId: 53, //their conversation id
    created_at: "2023-03-07T13:15:50.000000Z",
    id: 3,
    message:"hello",
    name: "Anna Doe",
    receiver: 1, // id of the user who will receive the message
    seen: null,
    sender: 3, //id of the user who sends the message
    updated_at: "2023-03-07T13:15:50.000000Z"
  },
  {
    avatar: null,
    convoId: 53, //their conversation id
    created_at: "2023-03-07T13:15:50.000000Z",
    id: 3,
    message: "hello",
    name: "Anna Doe",
    receiver: 3, // id of the user who will receive the message
    seen: null,
    sender: 3, //id of the user who sends the message
    updated_at:"2023-03-07T13:11:16.000000Z"
  }
]
```

to understand more the image is shown below:

first message:
[image: user sends "hi" message]

then after sending another message:
[image: second message]

after sending another message:
[image: third message]

as you can see the first message being send is updated with the new sent message.

can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like that might be due to these few lines

```js
if(storeChat.conversation.length == 0)
  storeChat.conversation.push(res.data)
else{
  storeChat.conversation.unshift({...res.data})
}
```

I see that you are creating a new object in `unshift` but not on `push`

Although it is not making sense to me why `res.data` would be getting reused, based on the results it seems to indicate that `res.data` is an instance that is getting updated instead or replaced. If that is the case this should fix it

```js
storeChat.conversation.push({...res.data})
```

Comment: thanks for that, it solved my problem, but i don't really understand why

Comment: it appears that `res` and therefore `res.data` is being reused. So every time it gets updated, the value of the first item updates. The other instances are not affected, because the `unshift` method used a copy of the instance of `res.data` at the time of adding to the array